# no ethernet on centos7

Tags: centos

I don't run it in a virtual environment, but I install it on a computer as a boot disk and use it with Windows, but Ethernet works well in Windows.

There is no ethernet in centos7. I looked it up, and if I search with 'ifconfig', there are things like 'eth0' and 'enp33', but I have only 'lo' and 'vir0'.

how can i solve it?

Comment: Is there a file ```/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0``` if yes can you paste it here?

Comment: What is the output of `lspci | grep -i ethernet`

Comment: Anything network related in the boot logs?

Comment: The legacy `ifconfig` with no options will only display *configured* network interfaces; to also display unconfigured ones with drivers loaded, use `ifconfig -a`. If you still cannot see it, you'll need to identify the NIC chip and find out if there is a problem in loading its driver: `lspci -nn -d ::0200` should display all Ethernet-like NICs on a PCI(e) bus and also show the numeric vendor/product IDs. That will work even without a driver, and should help in identifying the NIC type.

Comment: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-centos-7-network-settings/